# Most efficient way to find the nearest number in a list

Tags: java

I know what they say *pre-optimization is the root of all evil* however I'm more curious here as to what is the most efficient way to do this. Just a little more to the knowledge pool, you know?

Basically I have a collection of integers, like so:

```
final List<Integer> list = ImmutableList.of(1, 5, 10, 27, 57, 193);
```

Now I want to find the nearest number, rounded down. So for example I have the number 192. So the returned value from this list will be "57". Same applies if the number was 58. It just finds the next lowest number.

Currently I'm looping through the list starting from the end, using a `for` then returning the index of the list, which would be the number that I want. I'm just curious as to if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Is the list sorted? Is this for consistent hashing?

Comment: Have you heard about quicksort?

Comment: From what I remember, via the big-O notation, a single loop is very efficient. Just return the absolute value of the subtraction, and bam, nearest number index.

Comment: `Collections.binarySearch` is the way to go.  If the list isn't sorted, use `Collections.sort` first.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: but if the array is sorted, you can do this in logarithmic time. Which outperforms linear time nearly always and with huge difference.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı: That's not the fastest if you only need the number once.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I was not suggesting to sort the list. I was planning to mention about quickselect.

Comment: If the list is under a certain limit, it's actually faster to just do a linear search.

Comment: @CommuSoft I'm not sure I follow. How is sorting it going to yield a better efficiency?

Comment: The better question is, how would I sort an immutable list? Either way it's always going to be sorted in ASC order.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: the example seems to imply the list is already sorted. Furthermore in case you are going to do a lot of queries, sorting the list first, will pay off in the end.

Comment: @Christian.tucker: what should be returned if such number does not exists. For instance if you query `0`?

Comment: @CommuSoft - An exception should be thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Generic list

If nothing is known about the list, iterating over the list and memorizing the currently best solution is indeed the most efficient one.

If you however plan to do such query thousands of times, you might first sort the list.

## Sorted list

If the list is sorted you can use the [`binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) method. This method returns the *insertion point of a new element*. In case the element exists, a positive index of that element is returned. Otherwise the *bitwise negation* of the insertion index is returned.

You can then call it with:

```
//only to be used if list is sorted (a priori)
public int closestValue (List<Integer> list, int value) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list,value);
    if(index < 0) {
        index = ~index-1;
    }
    return list.get(index);
}
```

[**jdoodle demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/nY).

The method will throw an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) in case there is no such element.

*Binary search* can be done in *O(log n)*, but only - as said before - if the list is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

If the list is sorted , then you can do the Binary Search on the list and You can get your no in Log(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list and then use a binary-search like method to find the nearest number.

Answer (score 0):

use ConcurrentSkipListSet, and floor(value) to get the value less than or equal to the value specified.
floor returns null if value argument is less than first value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Create a HashMap the size of your maximum value, then fill the map with key pair of the expected result. i.e map.put(6,5);map.put(7,5) and so on.

After that getting the correct value will be in O(1).

Of course the creation of the Map will take more time and recourse but over a infinite amount of time this will yield the fastest result.

Comment: That's not going to work, since the query can be anything: you could query for `2'000'000'000+`: you're going to construct a hashmap with more than 4GiB of elements? Will take all memory. Furthermore worst case a hashmap has a time complexity of *O(n)*. Furthermore the *setup* setup phase will take a lot of time.