# find the nearest number of a list

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I have a List of classrooms and a list of student groups. Each Classroom can only take in x amount of students. I want to find the best possible classroom for each group of students.

I have the following example.

```
List<Classroom> classRooms = new ArrayList<>();

classRooms .add(new Classroom("Lecture Room 1", 40));  
classRooms .add(new Classroom("Lecture Room 2", 32));
classRooms .add(new Classroom("Lecture Room 3", 80));
classRooms .add(new Classroom("Lecture Room 4", 50));
classRooms .add(new Classroom("Lecture Room 5", 26));
```

Classroom class is basic with a contructor of (classroomname,maxCapicity)
Then i have a list of student groups

```
List<StudentGroup> studentGroups= new ArrayList<>();

studentGroups.add(new StudentGroup("Group 1", 70));  
studentGroups.add(new StudentGroup("Group  2", 40));
studentGroups .add(new StudentGroup("Group  3", 10));
studentGroups.add(new StudentGroup("Group  4", 45));
```

if a group are assigned to a classroom the classroom should not be available anymore. Student group constructed looks similar to classroom where (groupname,totalStudents)

I looked at this [Most efficient way to find the nearest number in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384042/most-efficient-way-to-find-the-nearest-number-in-a-list) but i prefer not to use a list of integers (classroom sizes) and then removing each time from list. Is there a beter alternative ?

Thanks in advance.

## Edit I tried this . but dont think this will give the best possible result

```
Collections.sort(courseList, (a, b) ->         a.getStudentCount().compareTo(b.getStudentCount()));
     Collections.sort(classList, (a, b) -> a.getMaxStudente().compareTo(b.getMaxStudente()));

    // more course than classes
    if (courseList.size() > classList.size()) {

    } else { // more clases than courses

        for (int i = 0; i < courseList.size(); i++) {
            courseList.get(i).setDedicatedKlas(classList.get(i + 1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what should do with case then we have only one group with 45 and only two rooms with capacities 50 and 100. What to choose, 50 or 100? In my opinion it is better to choose 50 because in future we might have another group with 75. If it is no difference then algorithm can take 50 as well as 100.

Comment: my opinion is also to rather use the 50 in this case. Classrooms and groups sizes can change anytime . thus you are correct . is there an algorithm to choose the closest yet smaller or equals to the maxSize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to sort classrooms and groups. Next you need take biggest group and place to biggest classroom. On next iteration, take second group and place to second classroom.
For some big groups you can't take a classroom

```
classRooms = Collections.sort(classRooms , new Comparator<Classroom>() {
    public int compare(Classroom o1, Classroom o2)
    {
        return o1.getSize() < o2.getSize();
    }
});

studentGroups = Collections.sort(studentGroups, new Comparator<StudentGroup>() {
    public int compare(StudentGroup o1, StudentGroup o2)
    {
        return o1.getSize() < o2.getSize();
    }
});

int classRoomIndex = 0;
for(StudentGroup group : groups){
    while(classRoomIndex < classRooms.size()){
        Classroom classRoom = classRooms.get(classRoomIndex++);
        if(classRoom.getSize() >= group.getSize())
        {
            // place group to classroom
            break;
        }
    }
    if(classRoomIndex == classRooms.size()){
        // no classrooms for groups
        notInClass.addAll(groups.subList(groups.indexOf(group), groups.size()));
        break;
    }
    notInClass.add(group);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but dont think the result will be reliable. Is there a way to do this more dynamically or with an algorithm ?

Comment: @TinusJackson, what do you mean by "dynamically"? Lists can be varied during time, right? If yes then in when are you planning to place group in classrooms?

Comment: 1. Actual list sizes like classrooms and groups can change.
2. Classroom sizes and group sizes can change . Does this make sense?

not sure how to explain it better. There will be groups that might share the classroom if the subjects at a certain time will be the same and classroom will allow it. (this is not for now thought) i just need to find possible classrooms for groups

Comment: Algorithm is not responsible for this. You just update classrooms and groups data and run algorithm again if need it

Answer (score -2):

Why not sort both list and then assign from the top.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: So I am supposed to write up an essay on a homework? :-)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks :-)